# Zxing barcode source code integration to the Android project

Tags: android

I want to integrate the zxing source code to my Android application. I have downloaded the zxing1.5 and integrate the whole code to my application and I am calling the activity "CaptureActivity" through intent.

It is showing only the camera view but it is not scanning the barcode. How can I solve this problem - I want my application to be stand alone. I don't want to install BarcodeScanner.apk separately in the device.

Comment: I believe you want do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `CaptureActivity` is what you want - instead, you should be using `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN`.

See the article [How to scan a barcode from another Android application via Intents](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) for code samples, and links to further related articles.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but i don't want to call the "BarcodeScanner.apk" that has been already installed in the device. I want my application to be stand alone .So i want to integrate the zxing android code to my application.

hope you can understand.

Thanks

Comment: @Sujit: Ah, I see.  Then I guess you need to merge the original ZXing XML file with yours, but change `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` to `com.sujit.zxing.client.android.SCAN` or similar, and then fire an intent for `com.sujit.zxing.client.android.SCAN`.

Comment: original ZXing XML means AndroidMainefest.xml or what.

thanks...

Comment: Yes, AndroidManifest.xml.  Specifically the part that says `<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" ... > ... <intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>`

Comment: Ok i got it...let me test it on device

Thanks..

Comment: No its not working. I have changed the AndroidMainefest.xml and provide the package name as you have specified still it is not scanning at all. I am not getting it why it is not scanning. The BarcodeScanner android code is working fine and it is calling the CaptureActivity by intent but when i am calling the same activity in my application it is not scanning.

Thanks...

Comment: If you've changed everything to refer to your own package, and left everything else the same, then I'm afraid I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

I could do that! You need to copy the entries in `main.xml` which contain

```
"android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"
```