# is there any simple 1d barcode reader?

Tags: java, android, barcode

i am looking for a simple barcode reader for my android app. i only needs to be able to read the code and return it to me. i have already looked at zxing barcode reader but it is too complex and it seems to me that its focus is more on 2d barcodes and looking around the forums i found out that it has problems reading 1d codes if the phone doesn't have autofocus (maybe a general problem for all readers but still maybe another one handles them better).

any suggestions? 
tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used zxing before now for pure 1d bar-codes and i have got to say it couldn't be simpler, have you checked out: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Only downside is that the user needs the Zxing installed (although if they don't then they will be redirected to the market page for it).

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i did. but i would prefer if i had it implemented in my app.

Comment: I have found an article to do with what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690389/zxing-barcode-source-code-integration-to-the-android-project

Comment: yes i think this helps my case. so i suppose the next thing is to go trough the activity suggested in that answer and basicly the whole project and delete everything that is not needed. tnx.