# how to implement Zxing Intent Integrator.java in Android

Tags: android, barcode

I am working on bar code scanner.

I have Zxing IntentIntegrator.java file. I don't know how to use this File in my application to let my application work.

Comment: You want you application standalone or you just want to call the Zxing using intent.

Comment: I tried a lot to make my application standalone with Zxing but didn't get any solution . So i called it through intent. Here is my  question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690389/zxing-barcode-source-code-integration-to-the-android-project

Comment: so is there some other way i can implement my own Bar Code Scanner???

Answer (score 0):

Paste the `android_integration_supportv4.jar` (located at `zxing-2.1\android-integration`) into `libs` folder in your eclipse (adt) project tree.

You should than create dependencies by right click on the folder and selecting

```
build path->Configure build path...
```

In the dialog click the Add jar button and select the `android_integration_supportv4.jar` you just added.